# Wildcard selector jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, selector

I'm making a code that's toggling an explanation for something.
The code is:

```
jQuery('.button').click(function () {
       jQuery('#explanation').toggle();
});
```

I got multiple explanations: `#explanation1`, `#explanation2`, etc.

How can I wildcard select the number? Something like:

```
jQuery('.button').click(function () {
       jQuery('#explanation*').toggle();
});
```

I can't figure out, tried multiple solutions but none did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UsXmV/)**

Use this:

```
jQuery('.button').click(function () {
    jQuery('[id^="explanation"]').toggle();
});
```

---

References:

- [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 2):

Best solution is to put a class on every one and use that

```
<div id="explanation1" class="exp">...</div>
<div id="explanation2" class="exp">...</div>
<div id="explanation3" class="exp">...</div>

jQuery('.button').click(function () {
       jQuery('.exp').toggle();
});
```

Otherwise you'll have to use a [`starts-with` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) on the `id` attribute

```
jQuery('[id^="explanation"]').toggle()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
jQuery('[id^="explanation"]').toggle()
```

Comment: Or you can add the same class (`class='explanation'`) to every explanation element and then `$('.explanation')`

Comment: You could indeed, and it'd be better to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by id pattern : http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
 jQuery('.button').click(function () {
   jQuery('[id^="explanation"]').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('[id^=explanation]').toggle();
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

I needed like this:

```
if (jQuery(this).attr('name') == 'level_1' + wildcart)
```

I resolved with:

```
if (jQuery(this).attr('name').substr(0,7) == 'level_1')
```